# Multiple batches created in SQL Server when executing a stored procedure from a C# application

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I inherited an application written in C#, at some point this app executes a stored procedure via `SqlConnection` class, when the code does that, in SQL Server three different batches appear for the same session so my DBA is complaining about that telling that should not happen.

It uses multiple active results in the connection string since it's a global configuration and some other parts of the application need MARS but I don't see why this may be creating three batches since I'm only executing one stored procedure.

Here is the method I use to connect

```
    public async Task<ICollection<Label>> GetLabelsAsync(string ids)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using (var command = connection.GenerateCommand("[dbo].[GetLabels]"))
            {
                command.AddParameter(ids, DbType.String, "@labelDetails");

                var dr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                return dr.ToList<Label>();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the stored procedure I noticed when I open the SQL code three GO statements appear:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLabels] 
    @labelDetails AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    BEGIN TRY
        --Execute my sql code
    END TRY
END
```

May the first two `GO` in my sql code for `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` be creating the additional two batches they seem to be added automatically, or what may be causing this behavior?

**EDIT**

This seems to be just a weird behavior of MSSMS Activity monitor, the tool my DBA uses to monitor my database. When I use MARS three processes are detected however it doesn't execute three times but once. When I don't use MARS only one process is detected and the result is the same.

The below picture for reference, session 59 is without MARS, session 67 with MARS:

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: might be the problem with your async function

Comment: The GO keywords are not part of the stored procedure. Everything following the `AS` after the CREATE or ALTER statement is the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks TT. Yes, I know that and that's why I cannot understand this weird behavior, every `GO` is supposed to create a batch but first two are not part of the store procedure so still wondering why three processes are detected. As I mentioned in edit I think this is just a weird behavior from Activity Monitor.